# How to best mock module-level function reference in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

I have a Python module that is set up roughly like:

```py
from external_module import fn_a, fn_b

options = {
  "a": fn_a
  "b": fn_b
}

def foo(bar):
  options[bar]()
```

I would now like to write a test that the correct function from the external module is called:

```py
from my_module import foo

@mock.patch("external_module.fn_a")
@mock.patch("external_module.fn_b")
def test_foo(mock_a: MagicMock, mock_b: MagicMock):
  foo("a")
  foo("b")

  mock_a.assert_called_once()
  mock_b.assert_called_once()
```

Now because `options` is created at the module level and the import happens before the functions are mocked out the test fails.

So far I've come up with two solutions:

1. Wrap the function call in a `lambda`:

```py
options = {
  "a": lambda : fn_a()
  "b": lambda : fn_b()
}
```

2. Import the module in the test function:

```py
@mock.patch("external_module.fn_a")
@mock.patch("external_module.fn_b")
def test_foo(mock_a: MagicMock, mock_b: MagicMock):
  from my_module import foo
  foo("a")
  foo("b")
```

So far I'm leaning towards the latter solution, but I wonder if there is another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have realised that option 2 doesn't work if there are multiple similar tests, because the import happens only once in the same run. The resulting fix is also my preferred solution now:

```py
import my_module
from importlib import reload

@mock.patch("external_module.fn_a")
@mock.patch("external_module.fn_b")
def test_foo(mock_a: MagicMock, mock_b: MagicMock):
  reload(my_module)
  my_module.foo("a")
  my_module.foo("b")

  mock_a.assert_called_once()
  mock_b.assert_called_once()
```